# Creating a for loop in R for subsets of a dataframe with differing numbers of rows

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to create a for loop in R but I'm struggling.  For each subset in `nulo`, I would like to count the number of rows under a given set of conditions.

The code without the loop is below:

```
n<-as.data.frame(nulo[[10]])
dif<-max(n$x)-min(n$x)
a<-max(n$x)-(dif/3)
b<-max(n$x)-(2*(dif/3))
three<-data.frame("x" = n[which(n$x > a),])
two<-data.frame("x" = n[which(n$x < a & n$x > b),])
one<-data.frame("x" = n[which(n$x < b),])
rthree<-nrow(three)
rtwo<-nrow(two)
rone<-nrow(one)
```

This works and outputs the values I am looking for subset `10` in `nulo`, i.e. the number of rows in the first, second and third portions of subset `10`:

```
> rthree
[1] 14
> rtwo
[1] 10
> rone
[1] 10
```

However, I would R to automatically do this for every subset in my dataset and output something along these lines:

```
> rthree
[1] 14 13 12 10 18 15 13 12 16 14
> rtwo
[1] 10 9 11 8 7 13 12 8 12 10
> rone
[1] 10 5 7 9 8 6 10 7 9 10
```

My code is below:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
n[[i]]<-as.data.frame(nulo[[i]])
dif<-max(n[[i]])-min(n[[i]])
a<-max(n[[i]]$x)-(dif/3)
b<-max(n[[i]]$x)-(2*(dif/3))
three<-data.frame("x" = n[[i]][which(n[[i]]$x > a),])
two<-data.frame("x" = n[[i]][which(n[[i]]$x < a & n[[i]]$x > b),])
one<-data.frame("x" = n[[i]][which(n[[i]]$x < b),])
rthree<-nrow(three)
rtwo<-nrow(two)
rone<-nrow(one)
}
```

However I get this error:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(x = c(36.8085946064129, : replacement has 37 rows, data has 38

There is the added issue that the number rows in each subset is not the same.  I suspect this might be the cause of the error above but I'm not sure what to do about it and I'm not convinced that the rest of the loop will give me what I want.

Many thanks,

Carolina

The example dataset is below:

```
dput(nulo)

list(structure(c(14.4535912576178, 65.041031289951, 99.1902862358168, 
79.6135453386709, 101.485791269772, 99.2153169084766, 47.9814038225633, 
70.0948576858184, 74.9398399465637, 68.6669332362806, 86.649669083785, 
21.9979288437378, 35.3699143865736, 25.669760912146, 34.7010219621762, 
28.5579023781648, 71.8388973201484, 41.4441182136257, 56.8177084995736, 
78.3225677361615, 34.8036850175869, 62.4456287658962, 97.3669076500249, 
68.9938117814949, 37.8986839402404, 86.2760213886726, 86.381537673151, 
96.1147499379905, 81.2269865217262, 75.0928095855779, 87.5198120503622, 
89.8443882964527, 92.9950312510728, 3.375, 1, 1, 7, 5, 9, 11.5, 
12, 14, 20.75, 21, 23, 23, 24.5, 26.5, 28.5, 30.5, 32.875, 32, 
35, 36, 38.5, 41, 42, 44.5, 44, 46, 48, 55, 65, 65, 65, 65), .Dim = c(33L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic herbivore->Omnivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
"Aquatic herbivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Invertivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Omnivore->Frugivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", 
"Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Omnivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", 
"Scavenger->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore"), c("x", "y"))), structure(c(11.4070153884575, 
66.6097564569353, 86.3326081155118, 95.4806288857102, 95.6205964058567, 
10.2710724418706, 55.1386369154544, 54.0510813137216, 92.9037177295593, 
53.9107985020871, 90.4416191057169, 23.7020448869716, 27.471590619023, 
85.030976824538, 62.9635325178515, 42.1762227126562, 91.3557534874445, 
71.1352962260155, 78.8649510878066, 69.1990879346536, 75.1510501342993, 
86.6995136915932, 61.8026518825717, 73.3630268904497, 21.9995964487996, 
45.005908177246, 55.4034281724082, 97.1644299881326, 93.8528686498213, 
93.8859964402058, 89.1841422835556, 82.5533464718103, 97.3863618875403, 
81.4267663151549, 3.375, 1, 7, 5, 9, 33.0712890625, 11, 12, 14, 
20.75, 21, 25.5, 28.5, 28.5, 30.5, 32.875, 32, 33, 33, 35, 35, 
35, 36, 36, 38.5, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 55, 55, 65), .Dim = c(34L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Omnivore->Terrestrial herbivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", 
"Scavenger->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Omnivore->Frugivore", "Omnivore->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Omnivore", 
"Omnivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Vertivore->Scavenger", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Invertivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"), c("x", 
"y"))), structure(c(11.804572319727, 21.192712474945, 58.4915515690617, 
87.7413708605794, 96.7121735745528, 94.7456760384385, 53.651817944697, 
72.5422266029669, 85.4498443318947, 70.0230045776558, 73.8592180594859, 
90.4285589971233, 18.5076276902936, 39.437003242128, 75.3420337845822, 
24.996638484528, 40.9091556315949, 52.7595400596325, 100.558503053775, 
83.7737777054152, 54.5296450828475, 82.9184776409071, 38.0800066573814, 
61.4176036029378, 36.2206140133157, 48.481731455997, 39.0792341472932, 
41.0625225056599, 87.499845391008, 75.6048553140727, 85.1084770109575, 
63.986528621721, 89.114912426126, 57.9896119893616, 89.2245004392034, 
88.0872547723781, 3.375, 3.375, 1, 7, 5, 9, 11, 12, 12, 14, 20.75, 
21, 25.5, 28.5, 28.5, 30.5, 32.875, 32, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 36, 
38.5, 41, 42, 44.5, 45, 46, 48, 49, 49, 55, 55, 65), .Dim = c(36L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Scavenger->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", 
"Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Scavenger->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Scavenger->Invertivore", "Invertivore->Frugivore", 
"Scavenger->Omnivore", "Scavenger->Omnivore", "Scavenger->Granivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Scavenger", 
"Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Invertivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic herbivore->Aquatic predator", 
"Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Vertivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"
), c("x", "y"))), structure(c(79.9597208724071, 88.7709424329413, 
80.4224512963342, 98.6675644829155, 96.0978496242041, 0.346806932015386, 
45.757685965867, 70.835091683355, 79.2736978260814, 85.2669115060878, 
21.5304490612398, 94.0600300078478, 47.4684162913037, 47.8552845655713, 
22.3842338976321, 56.0719766884896, 82.239544950294, 82.1511756314875, 
43.3995659523273, 67.7523154437559, 46.5618250110849, 48.6677841555016, 
65.7658321189095, 39.5094932235561, 74.2126093688619, 84.8511636668304, 
35.7850114172769, 100.145621057346, 51.916667135273, 89.0258373910143, 
66.5338370993941, 79.1568758597529, 1, 1, 7, 5, 9, 33.0712890625, 
11.5, 11, 12, 14, 20.75, 21, 24.5, 26.5, 28.5, 30.5, 30.5, 32, 
33.75, 35, 36, 36, 38.5, 41, 42, 42, 44.5, 44, 46, 48, 55, 65
), .Dim = c(32L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Terrestrial herbivore->Granivore", 
"Granivore->Omnivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", 
"Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", 
"Frugivore->Aquatic herbivore", "Frugivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Scavenger", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Frugivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Vertivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"), 
    c("x", "y"))), structure(c(67.7362753443491, 99.4889289725079, 
79.5705156915655, 98.3789827308173, 99.6031870301004, 4.16911638614987, 
46.6735650992465, 60.2749905577944, 68.5323535006545, 69.2667455011688, 
60.0638378350162, 46.6095538785835, 59.6441877874263, 86.7563451495635, 
23.1076400784658, 19.4069305780725, 60.7257585817311, 78.7832002418826, 
56.7527956061554, 57.8295143352704, 96.0380538345073, 51.5705530225791, 
82.8812943559384, 62.1601470874623, 86.8401040478977, 75.7721585365652, 
87.6313043236582, 83.1229543100896, 79.1121836485137, 86.9776361989095, 
55.3936401701269, 56.2735693430641, 77.865406424026, 95.0743308555588, 
1, 1, 7, 5, 9, 33.0712890625, 11.5, 11, 11, 11, 14, 20.75, 20.75, 
21, 25.5, 30.09375, 28.5, 30.5, 32, 35, 36, 38.5, 41, 42, 42, 
44.5, 45, 46, 48, 48, 51, 51, 55, 65), .Dim = c(34L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic herbivore->Omnivore", 
    "Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Granivore", 
    "Granivore->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Scavenger->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Omnivore->Vertivore", "Omnivore->Invertivore", "Omnivore->Frugivore", 
    "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
    "Vertivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Invertivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"
    ), c("x", "y"))), structure(c(77.102114557558, 80.3300808087635, 
81.0562244023644, 55.3793287228569, 85.2420949853981, 99.2136790798106, 
94.6299461725774, 56.8600721962626, 83.1875941462581, 69.03915406489, 
78.029026338337, 54.4402605620789, 75.7587770620701, 94.9571528061097, 
24.172924015719, 68.9919762697084, 64.3308462605692, 37.2304741343462, 
64.5679711627374, 70.4767694222583, 75.2199152176873, 26.1581416158917, 
36.2344771466503, 99.4701679996216, 50.7859413479575, 46.0183564429234, 
61.9032674562417, 76.7903917583183, 91.3148920231282, 95.7559373898028, 
49.7534109880341, 79.2110735821494, 93.6695604893426, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 3.5, 5, 9, 11, 12, 14, 14, 20.75, 20.75, 21, 25.5, 28.5, 30.5, 
32.875, 32, 35, 36, 38.5, 41, 41, 42, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5, 44, 46, 
48, 55, 65), .Dim = c(33L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Invertivore->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", 
"Scavenger->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Frugivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic herbivore->Frugivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Invertivore->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"), 
    c("x", "y"))), structure(c(46.8339818956181, 91.7015959265765, 
82.8737077627242, 94.1837523723121, 96.2546295555518, 101.236238110431, 
42.0536291334168, 70.7298000854157, 97.8447232241848, 101.031851830279, 
47.8335604472022, 96.0790224385215, 29.6629559436552, 37.2407772837966, 
66.1499773414882, 60.0950687536576, 25.260562626904, 40.6690218388217, 
90.2838828056379, 78.5027383129536, 30.1550769912419, 44.5830270824629, 
36.1081629989443, 95.1275278794025, 90.5367613910354, 74.6170697627128, 
99.9828353780142, 46.8230945062715, 66.9120751447315, 84.3576050895445, 
70.3140162658237, 63.9917467582706, 87.3797764275514, 100.969149863686, 
1.5, 1, 3.5, 5, 5, 9, 11.5, 11, 14, 14, 20.75, 21, 24.5, 26.5, 
26.5, 28.5, 30.5, 32.875, 32, 35, 36, 38.5, 41, 41, 42, 44.5, 
44, 46, 48, 48, 55, 59, 59, 65), .Dim = c(34L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", "Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", 
    "Frugivore->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Aquatic herbivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Scavenger->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
    "Vertivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Omnivore->Frugivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", 
    "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
    "Aquatic herbivore->Frugivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Granivore", "Granivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Aquatic predator", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"), c("x", "y"))), structure(c(45.3569318899142, 
73.2148326588949, 78.9013518379497, 101.374375397175, 83.1699056188501, 
97.9506672286067, 92.127013089983, 23.4891054235469, 64.0444519518701, 
79.7226553388518, 46.2419826320717, 94.0347006830583, 18.7397290631359, 
56.5150363632013, 69.2680046736094, 36.8174275662614, 82.5184543765298, 
51.6837848647383, 86.3282798312234, 96.7110215980964, 52.0738434932516, 
54.2205649988113, 67.5742911323713, 81.5542030426174, 70.2355124104945, 
98.8906686454949, 92.0567346153192, 83.3228531645479, 91.1762681452512, 
76.4478319936976, 100.71473051491, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 3.5, 5, 9, 12.5, 
11, 13, 20.75, 21, 25.5, 28.5, 30.5, 32.875, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
36, 38.5, 41, 42, 44.5, 45, 46, 48, 55, 65, 65), .Dim = c(31L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Vertivore", "Vertivore->Aquatic predator", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Aquatic herbivore", 
"Omnivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", 
"Scavenger->Frugivore", "Scavenger->Omnivore", "Scavenger->Omnivore", 
"Scavenger->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Frugivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Invertivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
"Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
"Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore"), c("x", "y"))), structure(c(87.5226349652136, 
47.9757744974178, 87.1828585879162, 98.3742862758965, 97.8221547431392, 
17.1194312837854, 101.522332745767, 84.4206495170692, 84.8765376521159, 
55.2017050680528, 68.8558177222079, 89.2622983462536, 28.2781730935879, 
46.561672721099, 81.3709208969142, 71.0583844125783, 76.719286044677, 
38.9186984585495, 62.604383470183, 100.047156404558, 52.7886698299685, 
69.839291105531, 53.6788401385809, 69.6644461175523, 72.0417139732782, 
72.297134198076, 40.7794308382758, 42.7631646816075, 86.6307000959597, 
89.2017143832027, 92.0304565460602, 81.9359874849621, 80.1986071721993, 
2, 5.25, 7, 5, 9, 33.0712890625, 11, 12, 14, 20.75, 20.75, 21, 
24.5, 26.5, 28.5, 30.5, 30.5, 32.875, 32, 35, 36, 36, 38.5, 41, 
41, 42, 44.5, 44.5, 44, 46, 48, 55, 65), .Dim = c(33L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Omnivore->Terrestrial herbivore", "Omnivore->Terrestrial herbivore", 
    "Terrestrial herbivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Aquatic predator", 
    "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", 
    "Terrestrial herbivore->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", 
    "Vertivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Frugivore", 
    "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Scavenger", 
    "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Invertivore->Frugivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", "Scavenger->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Invertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"
    ), c("x", "y"))), structure(c(30.76392934429, 60.4966786575788, 
76.5022603652647, 70.7666876797647, 95.3030012131842, 79.4374273344583, 
97.016682438359, 93.1657120819106, 46.8823044288113, 53.7196262394581, 
86.6743827791268, 73.648200531466, 99.7877929814271, 20.5744238441954, 
18.2285722110618, 24.8260517394446, 37.3876636290666, 43.9641354261516, 
50.7316539478547, 83.4977556938382, 49.1047629769543, 76.6770873946229, 
23.6429895432459, 51.9013790686088, 22.5903043102943, 29.476239349665, 
68.0535291743622, 30.9418047300576, 93.4215506816363, 48.5205973765749, 
77.7367653432387, 83.772371043977, 89.5341636600179, 71.5194352222716, 
1.5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3.5, 5, 9, 11.5, 12, 14, 20.75, 21, 25.5, 35.015625, 
30.5, 32.875, 33.75, 33, 33, 34.5, 34, 36, 36, 42.625, 41.5, 
41, 44.5, 44, 46, 46, 48, 55, 65), .Dim = c(34L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Aquatic predator->Granivore", "Granivore->Scavenger", 
    "Scavenger->Omnivore", "Granivore->Invertivore", "Invertivore->Terrestrial herbivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Terrestrial herbivore", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Aquatic herbivore", 
    "Aquatic herbivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Granivore", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Vertivore", "Vertivore->Invertivore", 
    "Vertivore->Frugivore", "Frugivore->Aquatic predator", "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", 
    "Invertivore->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Granivore", "Granivore->Omnivore", 
    "Vertivore->Granivore", "Granivore->Scavenger", "Vertivore->Aquatic predator", 
    "Aquatic predator->Invertivore", "Invertivore->Frugivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Omnivore->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Scavenger", 
    "Scavenger->Invertivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", "Aquatic predator->Omnivore", 
    "Aquatic predator->Omnivore"), c("x", "y"))))
```

Comment: Please use ```dput``` to output your data frame (or data) and copy it into your question. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry!  I've edited the question.  Hope I've done it right!

Comment: Yes, thank you! I now works on my machine. However, do you mind adding the small example I asked you to provide below? Thank you!

Comment: I have just added it! Hope it explains what I want!

Comment: It gets clearer. However, I'm still confused what exactly your set is. Maybe it is actually the best way to provide an example with a data frame with 10 rows and 2 columns, as I suggested below. Or maybe even better, a list (you are working with lists) of length two where each entry is a data frame with 10 rows and 2 columns. I will help you if you provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to replace something with something else, and the replacement does not match the dimension of the former.

I suspect that the error is caused by this line.

```
n[[i]]<-as.data.frame(nulo[[i]])
```

Because this is the only time you try to replace something.

Save you output into a new list and the error should go away. For example.

```
# your code is here above ....

my.list <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
my.list[[i]]<-as.data.frame(nulo[[i]])
```

HTH!

Comment: Thank you!  That has solved that error!  Now the issue is that the output seems to only be giving me the number of rows for subset 10 as opposed to a vector with the number of rows for all the subsets.  How can I change the code to achieve this?

Comment: @CarolinaKaroullas I'm not sure what you exactly mean. Can you please add to your question a little example of what you mean? The example should be small (e.g. a data frame with 10 rows and 2 columns) and the **exact** output you expect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MacOs, I've figured it out.  The code below:

```
list <- list()
list1 <- list()
list2 <- list()
list3 <- list()
rthree <- list()
rtwo <- list()
rone <- list()

for (i in 1:10) {
  list[[i]]<-as.data.frame(nulo[[i]])
  dif<-max(list[[i]])-min(list[[i]])
  a<-max(list[[i]]$x)-(dif/3)
  b<-max(list[[i]]$x)-(2*(dif/3))
  list1[[i]]<-data.frame("x" = list[[i]][which(list[[i]]$x > a),])
  list2[[i]]<-data.frame("x" = list[[i]][which(list[[i]]$x < a & list[[i]]$x > b),])
  list3[[i]]<-data.frame("x" = list[[i]][which(list[[i]]$x < b),])
  rone[[i]]<-nrow(list1[[i]])
  rtwo[[i]]<-nrow(list2[[i]])
  rthree[[i]]<-nrow(list3[[i]])
  one<-as.numeric(rone)
  two<-as.numeric(rtwo)
  three<-as.numeric(rthree)
}
```

Outputs this:

```
> one
 [1] 20 21 18 17 19 20 19 20 22 17
> two
 [1]  9  8 14 12 12 11 12  9  9  9
> three
 [1] 4 5 4 3 3 2 3 2 2 8
```

The number of rows in each subset of my dataset with values above a certain threshold (`one`), within a certain threshold (`two`) and below a certain threshold (`three`)).

Thanks again!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help.